# Custom cache settings for JS/CSS resources

Tags: caching, response-headers

Is it possible to set the cache for `JS` and `CSS` files only based on some logic?

When the url of the assets always changes (e.g `SignUp.[versiontoken].css` when the content is modified) then the cache settings can be (1 year) `Cache-Control: max-age=31536000`

When the url is static (e.g `/ui/some.css`) then the cache should be short (`<1day`).

For the first scenario, I think is enough to add `Cache-control` in the `web.config`, but for the second one, what should I do?

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <remove name="Cache-Control" />
        <add name="Cache-Control" value="public, max-age=31536000" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Project: Sitecore 9.3 based on Helix architecture, no SXA

Comment: Can you give us more information? Like what Sitecore version are you using? How have you setup your JS/CSS? Is this SXA/JSS/Classic MVC? Based on your tags, if this is just static files on your server, then this is not the right place, you'd be better asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question it seems like these are static assets on your server which are perhaps generated by a frontend build process. I'm having a similar requirement and use an `outbound rewrite rule` to accomplish this, see sample below. Another approach would be to set this in `Application_BeginRequest`.

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="Set long cache time" preCondition="SetLongCache">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_cache-control" pattern="(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
    </rule> 
    <preConditions>     
        <!-- Change condition to meet your requirement -->
        <preCondition name="SetLongCache" >
            <add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="SignUp\.(.*)\.css" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

Comment: This is actually good. Is not quite what I need, but it helped a lot. Thanks